# Is there any web servers in java eco-system similar to phusion passenger?

Tags: java, webserver, jruby, passenger

Is there any  web servers or application servers for running java apps with following features offered by phusion passenger

**1) DYNAMIC PROCESS MANAGEMENT BASED ON TRAFFIC**

phusion passenger adjust the number of application processes dynamically based on traffic, and restart any crashed processes. This way we ensure that resource usage stays within defined limits.

**2) OUT-OF-PROCESS ARCHITECTURE FOR EXTRA RELIABILITY**

Passenger run applications and most support code outside the web server's address space. If any component fails, we automatically restart it with our watchdog.

As for as my understanding ruby on rails  servers creates or forks process for each request, In java servers for each request new threads will be created

Questions

1) In java eco-system any web servers or application servers do automatic restart on component failure or out off memory issues or any other internal isssues

Answer (score 0):

[Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/) can do **2)** with any app deployed in a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container. Marathon does not currently do auto-scaling based on traffic.

Marathon requires a [Mesos](https://mesos.apache.org/) cluster and a [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) cluster.

Marathon will run multiple instances of your docker image on your Mesos cluster and restart any that fail. Your docker images need to provide Marathon with a health-check endpoint. If the health-check fails, Marathon will kill the docker instance and start a new one.